# Cocoapods platform, what does it mean exactly?

Tags: ios, cocoapods

It is unclear to me what effect changing the platform value will have, can someone elaborate? Will this simply mean that an error gets thrown if minimum version requirements for a library are not met?

https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, if POD A supports iOS 4.0 and has a dependency on POD B which only supports iOS 7.0, an error will be thrown when trying to publish the POD A's pod spec.

It will also be used to populate the `iOS Deployment Target` build setting for the Pods target.

Comment: I am sotty I didnt get this answer. Do you mean if I setup my platform to 9.0. My app wont run on 11.0?

Comment: No, it means it will run iOS 9.0 and above (so 9, 10, 11, and so on)