# Why do i need to set platform in cocoapods?

Tags: cocoapods

I just started working with cocoa pods recently(should have done this a long time ago), and im wondering what should the value of platform be. For instance right now i have `platform :ios, 8.0`(there is tick marks around the 8.0 but i dont know how to escape them in the editor) which tells me that the minimum version of the code using these dependencies is iOS 8.0. Few questions.

1. Is my interpertation right about platform? If not what does platform really do?
2. Does this mean it will only install on version 8.0? If so how to i make it say version 8.0 and all higher versions?
3. So later on when ios version 9.0 comes out say certain dependencies don't work with ios 9.0. Do I need place `platform ios: 9.0` underneath the list of dependencies for 8.0 and add another list of dependencies for 9.0 to work with?

This is enough questions for now. Thanks for your help.

Example of number 3

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
target 'my target' do
//list of pods
end

platform: ios, `9.0`
target `my target` do
//list of pods
end
```

Comment: did you figure this out ? im wondering what to set platform to also

Comment: I found this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30806294/cocoapods-platform-what-does-it-mean-exactly